# Showing that stalk $O_{Spec \ A, p}$ is $A_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have $A$, a commutative ring with unity. I would like to show that 
stalk $O_{Spec \ A, p}$ is $A_p$ for $p \in Spec \ A$. Could someone please explain
me how this works? (I am having trouble showing that the map from 
$O_{Spec \ A, p}$ to $A_p$ is well defined.) Thanks!

Comment: Take a representative of some element of the stalk, restrict to a principal open where you can write it as $f/g$ with $g\notin \mathcal{P}$, and you have your map.  To show it's well-defined, look at what happens if you had a different representative on an smaller principal open.

Comment: @Slade This is what I am confused about. I understand that if I have $[(a,U)]$ in the stalk then I can find $D(g)$ so that say $[(a,U)] = [(f/g^n, D(g))]$ and then I can send it to $f/g^n \in A_p$. I thought maybe I was missing something, because I started with $[(a,U)]$, but I considered another representative instead, namely  $[(f/g^n, D(g))]$. Don't I need to be able to show what the image is (and that they are same) for every possible representative to prove the map is well defined? Thanks!

Comment: You wrote the same thing for the two different representatives.  The point is, what if you have $f/g^n$ on $D(g)$ and $f'/g'^n$ on $D(g')$?  Well, by assumption, there's some open subset of $D(g)\cap D(h)$ on which they agree, so restrict to a principal open $D(h)$ inside $D(gg')$.  See what equality there tells you.